# Travis CI считает, что тесты не выполняются. Но они выполняются

Tags: java, maven, travis

Команды в cmd выдают красивое Build Succes. И юнит-тесты зеленые. Программа работает как часы. Но стоит требование прогнать ее через Travis, и вот он-то считает, что крашатся все 4 теста и *"The command "mvn test -B" exited with 1."*, хотя все прекрасно отрабатывает через cmd.

Пока сетую на кодировку UTF-8. Дело в том, что программа выводит сообщение в соответствии с системным языком: для русскоязычных стран - на рус., для англоязычных - на англ. Могу проверить тесты только с "ru". Скорее всего, у Travis должно работать с "en". Но не работает. Может ли быть в этом причина? Если да, то возьмусь перекраивать код и засовывать перевод в проперти. Сейчас варианты перевода находится в куче в одном текстовом документе.

Ссылка на отловленные Трэвисом блохи: https://travis-ci.org/montgomeri15/GoodMorningToYou/builds/272647137

И кусочек юнит-теста на всякий:

```
 public class NeededMsgTest {

    private static final String morning_en = "Good morning, World!";
    private static final String morning_ru = "Доброе утро, мир!";

    String s = InputContext.getInstance().getLocale().getDisplayLanguage();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    Date date = new Date();
    int hour = Integer.valueOf(dateFormat.format(date));

    public NeededMsgTest() throws IOException {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void morning() throws Exception {

        NeededMsg neededMsg = new NeededMsg(s, hour);  //Обращение к тестируемому классу

        if (hour >= 6 && hour < 9){

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("en")){
                assertEquals(morning_en, neededMsg.morning());  //morning() - это метод класса NeededMsg: если яз. английский - выводится строка из текстового документа на англ., если на русском - строка на рус.
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("ru")) {
                assertEquals(morning_ru, neededMsg.morning());
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: У вас прямо в ошибке написано, где она возникает

Comment: 22 строка. Здесь "String s = InputContext.getInstance().getLocale().getDisplayLanguage();"

Comment: Значит, в цепочке `InputContext.getInstance().getLocale()` один из участников - null

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил следующим образом. Полностью убрал строку *InputContext.getInstance().getLocale()*. Вместо этого использовал:

```
ResourceBundle lang = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Lang");
```

И дальше уже работал с ним. Пришлось немного перекроить проект и создать проперти, но оно того стоит.

Может, кому-то пригодится.